# Creating a simple node.js static server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./'));
app.listen(80);
```

> The error msg I receive in the cli via "node server.js" is:
>   events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1245:19)
>       at listen (net.js:1294:10)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1390:5)
>       at EventEmitter.listen (G:\angular\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
>       at Object. (G:\angular\server.js:4:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>
> Any ideas why a simple bit of code would generate errors?  I got the
>   code from an older angularjs book I'm trying to learn from.   Changes
>   with node or express possibly?

Comment: You need to add the resource name as static route (eg. folder containing frontend code or html etc), not another route :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, all ports below 1024 are so called [Privileged Ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html). Only root or other specific system users can start services here.

When you're programming with a regular user (as you should), it's customary to start your dev server on ports above 1024. For web servers it's common to use `8080` or `3000`.

The error message `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80` also gave you a hint. `EACCESS` means that you do not have the rights to open a server on port 80. Only the root user does for running production code.

Also one piece of advice: AngularJS has changed *a lot* in the last years. So if you want to learn it, don't use an older book. Much of what you'd learn is probably obsolete and done differently now.

Comment: This worked for me.  just a simple change to another port made it work.  8080 is typically a port I use for serving local files but I thought I had already tried changing the port.  Big Help!  Also, I'm learning AngularJS not really nodejs but the book seems to be pushing a lot of node and express.  Either way...  Thanks for explanation and solution.

Comment: @Rogue33 Sure thing, happy to be of help^^

Enjoy learning Angular with some Node and Express along the way!

Answer (score 0):

`Error: listen EACCES` means you don't have permission to listen on that port. Try different port.

And static content should be served like this

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));`

`__dirname` represent current directory.

Answer (score -1):

This code is working for me, please try it:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', express.static(__dirname + 'your path'));

app.listen(80);
```